# Sidebar menu multiple hrefs?

Tags: html, href, repeat

So I currently have the following sidebar menu:

```
<div id="menu">
<h3>Menu</h3>
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="wiezijnwij/index.php">Wie zijn wij?</a>
<a href="diensten/index.php">Diensten</a>
<a href="producten/index.php">Producten</a>
<a href="service/index.php">Service</a>
</div>
```

When I'm on my home and I click the wiezijnwij page in the sidebar it redirects me to this page perfectly. However, when I'm on the wiezijnwij page and I click on the wiezijnwijpage again in the sidebar menu it redirects me to 
localhost/project/wiezijnwij/wiezijnwij/index.php

So, it's repeating wiezijnwij.. not sure why

Comment: Use absolute paths like `<a href="/project/wiezijnwij/index.php">Wie zijn wij?</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using relative URLs, so the browser appends the path the `href` to the directory in the current URL.
You want to use absolute URLs, starting with a `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can give your URLs absolute paths like:

```
<a href="/project/wiezijnwij/index.php">Wie zijn wij?</a>
```